# One-liner for "return object if found"

Tags: ruby, syntax

I currently use this code to directly return an object from a function if it is found in an array:

```rb
already_existing = my_array.find { |v| ... predicate ... }
return already_existing if already_existing
# ...
# Remaining of the function should be executed if object not found
```

Is there an elegant way to transform that into a one-liner?

**Note**: Without calling `find` twice of course, or calling `include?` first then `find` because it would have a performance hit)

Comment: How about `return true if my_array.find { |v| ... predicate ... }`?

Comment: I need to return the object itself also, otherwise yeah just an `include?` would do the trick

Comment: otherwise it can return nil ? Why not use just `return my_array.find { |v| ... predicate ... }`

Comment: I need to continue the flow of execution if the object is not found

Comment: Sorry, the name `already_existing` made me think it was just Boolean. I don't think there's one of those Ruby shortcuts that gets you there. You could just write, `return obj if (obj = my_array.find { |v| ... predicate ... })`, possibly without the parentheses.

Comment: yeah, tried that but rubocop said `obj` will not be used, which made me think scope would not be ok

Comment: By making it more compact, we've avoided having to reference the return object unnecessarily, but it leads to that warning. This might be a "choose your poison" scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use short-circuiting.

```
my_array.find { |v| ... predicate ... } or begin
  # the other logic
end
```

But I personally would go with `return existing if existing`. It's a case where cure is worse than the disease.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an elegant way to transform that into a one-liner?

Sure, there is! In fact, since newlines are optional in Ruby, *any arbitrarily complex Ruby program* can be turned into a one-liner:

```
already_existing = my_array.find { |v| ... predicate ... }; return already_existing if already_existing
```

Comment: Ahah it seems you're dropping the "elegant" here :)

Comment: "Elegant" is opinion-based and thus off-topic on [so], unless you provide an objectively quantifiable, precise, unambiguous, exact definition of "elegant". My solution works for every possible Ruby program ever written in the history of the universe, every possible Ruby program that will ever be written until the heat death of the universe, even every possible Ruby program that was never written and will never be written. It requires no knowledge whatsoever of the semantics of the code or even the semantics of Ruby, and can be mechanically applied by a machine. I would call that elegant.

Answer (score -2):

Facets library has [`#find_yield`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/Enumerable:find_yield) method. It can help organize code as one-liner. Also this can be done with 'map.detect' combination.
Basically you need to do `return something that found OR call other stuff`:

```
require "facets"
test_arrays = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]

# with facets library
test_arrays.each do |my_array|
  puts my_array.find_yield{ |i| j = i + 1; j if j % 4 == 0 } || "other_logic_result"
end
# => other_logic_result
# => 4

# with pure ruby methods
test_arrays.each do |my_array|
  puts my_array.lazy.map { |i| i + 1 }.detect { |j| j % 4 == 0 } || "other_logic_result"
end
# => other_logic_result
# => 4
```

Comment: `find_yield` would indeed help simplify code if we did any mapping/transformation. But we (well, Mic) don't. And so it's in no way better than `find`. Therefore, we're back to square one.

Comment: Then we can do `return my_array.find { |v| ... predicate ... } || call_other_code`

Comment: Yes, I am of the same opinion. The only problem is that this "other code" seems to be the rest of the method.

Comment: We could extract `other code` to a separate method then. This could be more readable. But it depends on a context of course. Personally I try to avoid `begin-end` blocks in code but it's just a matter of taste.